# HTML/jQuery Limit no. of divs in container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

(firstly I recommend seeing the related image)
I have 3 container having same class .container. Also, user can add child divs dynamically into the containers. The user will start adding divs (that is .parent) by clicking '.add' div inside each '.parent'.
The containers can have at max 3 div. If the user has added 3 divs already then the next div should go in the second container and so on. Once the last container(the third one) is full, an alert should pop up saying "You cannot add anymore divs."

I have two questions:

Using jquery how can I limit the number of '.parent' divs per container to 3. If the user tries to add another it is added to container 2 (unless container 2 has 3 child divs, then it would go to container 3)?

Once the container of page 3 is full (3 divs) an alert should pop up saying "You cannot add anymore divs".

The only snippet of code that I have is not working. Please help me with the code. I am novice in all this stuff.

Thanks in advance.

Related image:  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zi78d.png

Sample code:

```
<html>// the containers
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="container"></div>//divs that are supposed to be appended
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="add"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="add"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="add"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="add"></div>
    </div>. . .
</html>
```

.

```
  <script>
   var $pages = $('.container');
   var child = '$('.add ').parent()';

   $(".add").on('click', function () {

       var childAdded = false;
       $pages.each(function () {
           var $container = $(this);
           if ($container.children().length < 3) {
               $container.append.('child');
               childAdded = true;
               return false;
           }
       });
       if (!childAdded) {
           alert("You can not add any more divs");
       }
   });
       </script>
```

Comment: are you wanting to clone `.parent`? Not really clear what you are trying to do

Comment: No cloning. I want to detach and append.

Comment: There're not enough `.parent` to go into `.container` without cloning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems in your code

You want the instance of the `parent` class when you click on the button, not all `.parent`

You have syntax errors using quotes around jQuery objects that shouldn't be there.

Here's a simple approach using `filter()` method.

```
$(".add").on('click', function () {
    /* filter $pages down to first available one with space */
    var $page=$pages.filter(function(){
           return $(this).children().length < 3;
    }).first();

    if( !$page.length ){ /* if no elements returned from filter, they are all full */
       alert("You can not add any more divs");          
    }else{
       /* get instance of parent based on button that was clicked which is "this" */
       var $parent=$(this).closest('.parent');
       $page.append( $parent );
    }     
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uMdsQ/)**</kbd>

**[filter() API docs](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)**

Comment: you were actually getting pretty close with code you started. I just used a slightly different approach but your approach would work also once you isolate the instance of `add`

Answer (score 1):

You have to track the amount of divs you have added yourself. Then, use this information to determine which `.container` you should put it in. Something like this:

```
var added = 0;

...

$(".add").on('click', function () {
    var target;
    if(added<3) {
        target = $pages[0];
    } else if (added<6) {
        target = $pages[1];
    } else if (added<9) {
        target = $pages[2];
    } else {
        alert("You can not add any more divs");
        return
    }

    $(target).append($(this).parent());
    added += 1;
```

Comment: not very scaleable , what if there are 50 $pages or quantity is unknown?

Comment: @charlietfl probably going to use `Math.floor(added/3);` assuming all elements are added sequentially. But that's likely the simplest way to do it.

Comment: can also use `$pages.eq(/*index*/)` instead of getting the node and wrapping in `$()` again